# MUI DataGrid sorting - is it possible to consider multiple columns when defining a default sortModel?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a data model that contains 3 different date fields (`estimateDue`, `workStartDue`, `workEndDue`). I have a requirement that states that, for each row, the default sorting should consider all 3 date fields, identify the soonest and use that value for the sorting for that row.

So, for example, if a the `estimateDue` value is soonest, then that value should be used, but for another row `workStartDue` might be soonest, so that value should be used. These values should then be used for sorting the rows.

Is this possible? I've read as much as I can find about defining the default `sortModel`, but have been unable to find anything suggesting how this could be done.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to add a column where you derive its value from other columns. Then you can sort on that new column. My example is leveraging `maturityDate` and `dateCreated` in the demo data from the docs, but you could apply the same idea to your 3 dates.

```
  {
    field: "earliestDate",
    headerName: "Earliest Date",
    type: "date",
    width: 150,
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      if (params.row.maturityDate < params.row.dateCreated) {
        return params.row.maturityDate;
      }
      return params.row.dateCreated;
    }
  }
```

[image: Edit derived sort]

Comment: Of course! Disappointed I didn't think of this! Many thanks indeed.